# How to pad string based on digits in a number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have an arbitrary number:

```
my_number = 898
```

I want to create a loop that counts up to that number, using a padding for the current count equal to the digits of that maximum number. In other words, if `my_number` is 5 digits long, then when the count is at 1 it should read `----1`, where each `-` is one space in the padding. Likewise, if we're at number 500 then it should be padded like so: `--500`. Example loop:

```
for i in range(my_number):
    print( '{}: Current Number'.format(i) )
```

I hope I'm clear. I just don't know what the 'pythonic' way of doing this would be. I imagine there is some clean way of doing this in python but I can't help but think of a cumbersome solution that would require several lines of code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [right-aligned `format` specifier](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html?highlight=string%20common%20string%20operations#format-specification-mini-language) for it:

```
In [23]: num = 15

In [24]: for x in range(num):
    print("{0:>{1}}".format(x, len(str(num))))
   ....:     
 0
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
10
11
12
13
14
```

Comment: You can do `{:->{}}` to make it dashes instead of spaces :)

Comment: Which happens to also be a smiley face :D

Comment: @soon Yes, it seems you're right, I should have read the question more carefully; the +1 still stands!

Comment: @Haidro, Note, that the OP wants spaces, not dashes. Quote from the question: _"...it should read `----1`, where each `-` **is one space in the padding**."_. But you're right - your smiley is better than mine :)

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
>>> my_number = 15
>>> for i in range(my_number):
...     strung = str(i)
...     print('-'*(len(str(my_number))-len(strung))+strung) # If you want spaces instead of dashes, do print(' '*(len(.......
... 
-0
-1
-2
-3
-4
-5
-6
-7
-8
-9
10
11
12
13
14
```

Comment: No, I believe he wants it so:
One digit #'s have no padding.
Two digits have one -
Three has --
Etc.

Comment: @Haidro Is there a reason why you changed from string to strung?  (just wondering)

Comment: @sihrc Just to avoid the repetitive calling of `str`

Comment: @EliasBenevedes I edited that right as you put in that comment :)

Comment: @Haidro Nope, still not right. One digit numbers have NO padding, two digit numbers have 1.

Comment: @Haidro OP wants the number of digits minus one as the buffer for the value.

Comment: @EliasBenevedes I'm still not understanding you. The OP says if the number is 5 digits long, then it should be `----1` (as my answer does). At 500, it should be `--500` (as my answer does too). Oh, you're probably reading my first answer. Let me remove that

Comment: @Haidro All right, I completely fooled that one up. You're doing it the right way.