# Setting field width and right justified in a loop python

Tags: python

I have a loop that when running with the rest of my program, it prints out a list of integers, 10 per line.

```
values.sort()
counter = 0
for i in values:
    counter += 1
    print(i, end=('  ' if counter < 10 else '\n'))
    if counter == 10:
        counter = 0
```

I'm trying to add to it to make it right-justified and the width is number length + 1.

That is: 
if my biggest number is 2 digits, it will look:

```
 11 16 12 

 42 32 41
```

if my biggest number is 3 digits, it will look like:

```
   33  58  21  69  

  121 111 403
```

4 digits (or negative):

```
 -232 -195 -199 -169 
 -151 -153 -149
```

I've tried:

```
for i in values:
    counter += 1
    print('{0:>{1}}'.format(i, len(values)), end=('  ' if counter < 10 else '\n'))
    if counter == 10:
        counter = 0
```

but it creates a disaster...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pad string based on digits in a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904848/how-to-pad-string-based-on-digits-in-a-number)

Comment: see edits kaya3

Comment: Is the problem that you don't know how to write a format specifier with a non-constant number? Just print the format to a variable, using len(values[-1]), and then use that format specifier in the print. Oh but the longest might also be the smallest, if it's negative.

Comment: The program processes through a binary file, sorts the integers, and prints them out using this loop. However, i didnt think that extra code would be helpful in any way to put into this question.

Comment: Yes @KennyOstrom there are a number of things going on in this such as the negative value, right justification, and not knowing how to properly write the format specifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're basically trying to pad each value's display to make a kind of column effect. In order to do that, you have to find the length of the biggest 'column'. Fortunately, since the list is already sorted, you just need the last index (values[-1]).

Taking that value, you can specify the whitespace for each number your for loop processes.

```
    values.sort()
    counter = 0
    for i in values:
        # find the difference in length between the longest item and current iteration
        # len(str(x)) = length of the string version of the variable "1" = 1, "11" = 2
        padding = len(str(values[-1])) - len(str(i))
        new_string = (" " * padding) + str(i)
        counter += 1
        print(new_string, end=('  ' if counter < 10 else '\n'))
        if counter == 10:
            counter = 0
```

Setting the values variable to:

```
values = [13, 122, 423, 633, 44, 254, 91, 253, 4, 210, 22, 212, 323, 333, 404, 154, 991, 223, 114, 110, 211, 212, 313, 33, 414, 554, 99, 223, 114, 11]
```

returns the following output:

```
  4   11   13   22   33   44   91   99  110  114
114  122  154  210  211  212  212  223  223  253
254  313  323  333  404  414  423  554  633  991
```

EDIT: The other answer was posted as I was toying around with this, but I figure I'll leave this just in case, since they're different methods to get the same result.

EDIT 2:

What's happening here is you're 1. defining a list (values), then 2. sorting that list (values.sort()), then 3. looping through the list (for i[tem] in values), which then 4. executes a task that manipulates the item of the list being looped.

So long as everything follows this order, you will get the same result. Whether you define the list manually (eg. 'values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]') or randomly, for the purposes of the program you are doing the same thing. To try to translate what the machine is doing:

```
1: get '[2,110,3,5,4,6,10,8,9,7]'
2: sort what I got to '[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,110]'
3: for '2', take the number of characters in the last list item(3) 
  [or the largest item if you are using max] and subtract the (1) 
  from it, giving me 2.
4: insert " " multiplied by the result of [3]. "  ". 
  then add '2' to this. "  2".
5: advance counter
6: print "  2 " since the counter is less than 10.
7: return to 3.
3: for '3', take...
```

You get the idea. Changing how you define values is only going to change what the script gets in '1'. I hope this was enlightening versus boring.

Comment: Awesome thank you so much. This is great and very clear. One question I have is regarding the padding variable. Right now you're using Len() function. If this program was changed a bit and outputted random integers, how would that change this? Because padding = max(values) - len(str(i)) would not work correct?

Comment: Do you mean that if instead of a list of integers the program fed it random integers? If that is the case, you could come at it a few ways. You could generate the list beforehand, then run it through the loop. If you must do it on the fly, I would experiment with generating each line as its own string and counting the whitespace vs digits. Something like get the len(string), loop a counter for 'if/else i == " "', then add whitespace. Could you give an example of what code would be different?

Comment: So if the list is generated beforehand it should run identical?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit this answer to provide a little more detail.

Answer (score 0):

The duplicate link is good for setting the width. You were doing it in end, which is probably less clear. But you aren't checking the length of your strings to determine what padding you want.

```
values = [11, 16, 12, 42, 32, 41, 99999]
values.sort()

# the longest string will be either the first or last 
# in the sorted list (most negative or most positive)    
format_width = 1 + max(
    len(str(values[0])), 
    len(str(values[-1])))

# here is the format string to pass to print
# based on the duplicate linked by kaya3
format_string = '{0:>' + str(format_width) + '}'

# print using the calculated format string, 
# which has the actual padding size    
for index, value in enumerate(values):
    print (format_string.format(value), 
           end='\n' if 0 == index+1 % 10 else '')
```